# ASP.NET MVC One to Many Database Table Values with List Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, one-to-many

My First Table is:

First Table Name: Contacts
ContactID (PK)
FirstName
LastName
Company

Second Table Name: Phones
ContactID (FK)
PhoneType
PhoneNumber

My view Model is

```
public class ContactVM2
{
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }

    public string PhoneType { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Repository Class is

```
public class ContactRepository
{
    ContactsDBEntities dbRepo = new ContactsDBEntities();

    public List<ContactVM> GetAllContacts()
    {
        List<ContactVM> ContactViewList = new List<ContactVM>();

        var allContacts = dbRepo.Contacts.ToList();
        var allPhones = dbRepo.Phones.ToList();

        foreach (var cont in allContacts)
        {
            foreach (var ph in allPhones)
            {
                if (cont.ContactID == ph.ContactID)
                {
                    ContactViewList.Add(new ContactVM(){
                        ContactID =cont.ContactID,
                        FirstName=cont.FirstName,
                        LastName=cont.LastName,
                        Company=cont.Company,
                        PhoneType=ph.PhoneType,
                        PhoneNumber=ph.PhoneNumber});
                }
            }
        }

        return ContactViewList;
    }        
}
```

and Controller is

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ContactRepository contRepo = new ContactRepository();

        var allContacts = contRepo.GetAllContacts().ToList();

        return View(allContacts);
    }
```

I have following data in Contacts tables
ContactID    FirstName   LastName   Company
1                  Bill                Gates       Microsoft

and in Phones Table
ContactID    PhoneType      PhoneNumber
1                Home                1111
1                Office                2222

I am getting following result
1    Bill    Gates    Home    1111
1    Bill    Gates    Office    2222

Where Contact details are repeating.
I need following result
1    Bill    Gates    Home    1111
                            Office    2222
I have also tried following changes in View

```
 <td style="border:2px solid Blue;">
        @{
        foreach (var parent in Model.Where(x=>x.ContactID==item.ContactID).GroupBy(m=>m.PhoneNumber))
       {   
          foreach( var itm in parent )
           {                
             @itm.PhoneNumber <br />
          }    
          } 
          }
    </td>
    <td style="border:2px solid red;">
        @{
        foreach (var parent in Model.Where(x=>x.ContactID==item.ContactID).GroupBy(m=>m.PhoneType))
       {   
          foreach( var itm in parent )
           {                
             @itm.PhoneType <br />
          }    
          } 
          }
    </td>
```

But it still repeats the record again.
Then I tried following changes in ModelView

```
    public List<string> PhoneType { get; set; }
    public List<string> PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

but did not get results.
**Can any one help by giving simplest example as I am at very beginner level.**
Code without Phone Iteration in View

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Company)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhoneType)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhoneNumber)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You are iterating the Phone loop. so there was two phone number for Id 1. So it is repeating the two rows

Comment: I have tried without iteration still getting contact details twice.

Comment: Can you add that code also?

Comment: @Deepak.Aggrawal Code without Iteration added at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the iteration from repository class  and create  a separate class for Phone number and add the variable of that class in ContactVM2 like the the below model:

```
public class ContactVM2
{
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public List<ContactVM2Phone> PhoneList {get; set;}

}
public class ContactVM2Phone
{
    public string PhoneType { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

**Repository class**

```
public class ContactRepository
{
    ContactsDBEntities dbRepo = new ContactsDBEntities();

    public List<ContactVM> GetAllContacts()
    {
        List<ContactVM> ContactViewList = new List<ContactVM>();


        var allContacts = dbRepo.Contacts.ToList();
        var allPhones = dbRepo.Phones.ToList();

        foreach (var cont in allContacts)
        {
          ContactViewList obj=   new ContactVM()
           obj.ContactID =cont.ContactID;
           obj.FirstName=cont.FirstName;
           obj.LastName=cont.LastName;
           obj.Company=cont.Company;
           List<ContactVM2Phone> Phonelist= new List<ContactVM2Phone>();
            foreach (var ph in allPhones)
            {
                if (cont.ContactID == ph.ContactID)
                {
                    Phonelist.Add(new ContactVM2Phone(){
                        PhoneType=ph.PhoneType,
                        PhoneNumber=ph.PhoneNumber});
                }
            }
           obj.PhoneList =Phonelist;
           ContactViewList.Add(obj);
        }

        return ContactViewList;
    }        
}
```

Comment: how to populate the list in this case?

Comment: Updated the answer. I have not run this code, so please check if there would be any minor error

Comment: I am checking it. Thanks

Comment: It is repeating all phone numbers in db on each row and all records are repeated again and again.